# how to deploy Kubernetes nginx controller with kubeadm (k8s 1.4)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

AWS + Kubeadm (k8s 1.4)
I tried following the README at:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx

but that doesnt seem to work. I asked around in slack, and it seems the yamls are out-dated, which i had to modify as such

first i deployed default-http-backend using yaml found on git:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/default-backend.yaml

Next, the ingress-RC i had to modify:

> https://gist.github.com/lilnate22/5188374

(note the change to get path to `healthz` to reflect `default-backend` as well as the port change to `10254` which is apparently needed according to slack)

Everything is running fine
`kubectl get pods` i see the ingress-controller
`kubectl get rc` i see 1 1 1 for the ingress-rc

i then deploy the simple **echoheaders** application (according to git readme):

```
kubectl run echoheaders --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --replicas=1 --port=8080
kubectl expose deployment echoheaders --port=80 --target-port=8080 --name=echoheaders-x
```

next i created a simple ingress :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: echoheaders-x
    servicePort: 80
```

both `get ing` and `describe ing` gives be a good sign:

```
Name:           test-ingress
Namespace:      default
Address:        172.30.2.86   <---this is my private ip
Default backend:    echoheaders-x:80 (10.38.0.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path    Backends
  ----  ----    --------
  * *   echoheaders-x:80 (10.38.0.2:8080)
```

but attempting to go to nodes public ip doesnt seem to work, as i am getting "unable to reach server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for all those that came here wondering the same thing..here is how i solved it.

PRECURSOR: the documentation is ambiguous such that reading the docs, i was under the impression, that running through the README would allow me to visit http://{MY_MASTER_IP} and get to my services...this is not true.

in order to get ingress_controller, I had to create a service for ingress-controller, and then expose that service via `nodePort`. this allowed me to access the services (in the case of README, `echoheaders`) via http://{MASTER_IP}: {NODEPORT}

there is an "issue" with nodePort that you get a random port#, which somewhat defeats the purpose of ingress... to solve that i did the following:

First: I needed to edit kube-api to allow a lower nodePort IP.

`vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.json`

then in the kube-api containers arguments section add: `"--service-node-port-range=80-32767",`

this will allow nodePort to be from 80-32767.

** **NOTE**: i would probably not recommend this for production...**

Next, i did `kubectl edit svc nginx-ingress-controller` and manually edited nodePort to port 80.

this way, i can go to {MY_MASTER_IP}  and get to echoheaders.

now what i am able to do is, have different Domains pointed to {MY_MASTER_IP} and based on host (similar to README)

Comment: I'm trying to expose my ingre controller but it didn't work. Can you please provide us with an example of the service ?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems that using ingress controllers with Kubernetes clusters set up using kubeadm doesn't is not supported at the moment.

The reason for this is that the ingress controllers specify a **hostPort** in order to become available on the public IP of the node, but the cluster created by kubeadm uses the [CNI](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/network-plugins/#cni) network plugin [which does not support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/31307) **hostPort** at the moment.

You may have better luck [picking a different way to set up the cluster](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/) which does not use CNI.

Alternatively, you can edit your ingress-rc.yaml to declare "hostNetwork: true" under the "spec:" section. Specifying [hostNetwork](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_podspec) will cause the containers to run using the host's network namespace, giving them access to the network interfaces, routing tables and iptables rules of the host. Think of this as equivalent to "docker run" with the option --network="host".

Comment: what does adding hostNetowkr: true do?

Btw, i was able to get this "running" by a bit hackish:

exposing ingress-controller as a service, and then exposing the service as a nodePort.

Comment: I've now added information about what "hostNetwork: true" actually does in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the image nginxdemos/nginx-ingress:0.3.1 ,you need not build yourself

Comment: i am not building my own, i am using the ingress from nginx
gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3

Answer (score 0):

@nate's answer is right

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service

has a bit more details.

They do not recommend setting the service's node port range though

Answer (score 0):

This question is the first in the search results of Google, I will add my solution.

kubeadm v1.18.12

helm v3.4.1

Yes, the easiest way is to use helm. Also I use standard ingress https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Add the repository

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

Install ingress

```
helm install ingress --namespace ingress --create-namespace --set rbac.create=true,controller.kind=DaemonSet,controller.service.type=ClusterIP,controller.hostNetwork=true ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Daedmonset makes ingress readily available on every node in your cluster.

*hostNetwork=true* specify uses the node public IP address.

After that, you need to configure the rules for ingress and set the necessary DNS records.